# How to limit ram usage of a certain binary?

Tags: linux, memory, cpu-usage

i have a binary, which indexes some stuff, it eats all my ram and my swap. Then the server hangs.

I would like to limit its ram usage.

I've looking at cpulimit and /etc/security/limits.conf but both of them focus on cpu limits and user/processes .

Have somebody limited the usage of a certain binary? How can I approach this issue?

Thanks

Comment: You do this per-user with ulimit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ulimit`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ulimit). In particular `ulimit -m`.

Answer (score 0):

`limits.conf` has several entries to limit memory usage you may consider, i.e. `data`, `rss`, `stack`.